# Teste jasmine jsmodular

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have this structure, need to be tested in jasmine. will be that like?

```
var APP =APP || {};
APP.modules = {};
APP.modules.execute = function(callback) {
    callback.return100 = function() {return "ABCa";};
};
```

I do not know if this was the best solution but Run:

```
APP.modules.execute = function (module) {
  /* start-test-block */
   var module = this;
  /* end-test-block */

   module.return100 = function() {return "AsaBC";};
/* start-test-block */
   return {
      return100: module.return100
   };
/* end-test-block */
```

---------to pass the test to remove test-block with strip_code

```
expect(APP.modules.execute().return100()).toBe("AsaBC");
```